# Public Class and App_Code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I can get my function working on one page but when I want to call the function from the App_Code folder I get an error on the "CreateSentence" part saying is is referenced to a non-shared member.

If someone has a simple shared function example (where the function is in the App_Code folder and not on the same page) or can point out the error I would be greatful.

Pages - 3

1 - Default.aspx

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Create Sentence" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="word" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
    <asp:Label ID="sentence" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

2 - Default.aspx.vb

```
Imports Functions

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        sentence.Text = CreateSentence(word.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

3 - App_code/Class1.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class Functions

    Function CreateSentence(ByVal word As String) As String

        Dim Sentence As String = "The world you have is: " & word & "."

        Return Sentence

    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply edit your function to be shared:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class Functions

    Public Shared Function CreateSentence(ByVal word As String) As String

        Dim Sentence As String = "The world you have is: " & word & "."

        Return Sentence

    End Function

End Class
```

Maybe giving this article a read would help in your understanding for the future: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be shared:

```
Public Shared Function CreateSentence(ByVal word As String) As String
   Dim Sentence As String = "The world you have is: " & word & "."
   Return Sentence
End Function
```

Then you can call the function within your page `Functions.CreateSentence`:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   sentence.Text = Functions.CreateSentence(word.Text)
End Sub
```